# Emacs + Zsh unexpected linebreaks

Tags: emacs, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm new to Emacs, and I'm trying to switch my workflow to using my terminal through Emacs.

I'm a Zsh user, and I love my terminal. I've been fiddling around with ansi term for a while now, and got my encoding sorted out.

But there's one issue that remains, and can be seen in the screenshots below:

This is what my terminal looks like in iTerm2 (with oh-my-zsh):

[image]

And this is what it looks like in ansi term (iTerm2, Emacs):

[image]

I'm curious what creates these strange line breaks and `%`-characters.

Anybody have a clue?

Comment: Just a note, as you logged off #emacs: having TERM set to xterm, is probably part of the problem, as Emacs ansi-term _isn't_ xterm, and if zsh thinks it is, it will do things that ansi-term probably doesn't understand.   The default TERM setting for ansi-xterm seems to be "eterm-color", so I'd try setting TERM to that ("TERM=eterm-color" in the shell), and see whether zsh is better behaved.

Comment: If I strictly define TERM to be eterm-color. The issues remain the same, and I get coloring issues (ie. '4m' pops up before my prompt). Currently I use this '[[ $TERM == eterm-color ]] && export TERM=xterm' in my .zshrc, which the coloring issue.